# Entity Framework Core : relational tables many-to-many - insert existing data

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've tried to insert relational data (some data already exists in my database). How can I create a music with my exist category and mood?

I get this error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_AgeRates"
>
> DETAIL: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.`

**Entities**

[image: Music]

[image: Category]

[image: Mood]

[AgeRateUpdated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYzYX.png)

Existing data:

[image: Moods]

[image: Category]

My code:

```
public record Command(CreateMusicRequest Model) : ICommand<Response<CreatedMusicResponse>>;

public class CommandHandler : ICommandHandler<Command, Response<CreatedMusicResponse>>
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<Music> _musicRepositoryAsync;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<Category> _categoryRepositoryAsync;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<Mood> _moodRepositoryAsync;
    public readonly IGenericRepository<AgeRate> _ageRateRepositoryAsync;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public CommandHandler(IGenericRepository<Music> musicRepositoryAsync,
          IGenericRepository<Category> categoryRepositoryAsync, 
          IGenericRepository<Mood> moodRepositoryAsync,
          IGenericRepository<AgeRate> ageRateRepositoryAsync,
          IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _musicRepositoryAsync = musicRepositoryAsync;
        _categoryRepositoryAsync = categoryRepositoryAsync;
        _moodRepositoryAsync = moodRepositoryAsync;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _ageRateRepositoryAsync = ageRateRepositoryAsync;
    }

    public async Task<Response<CreatedMusicResponse>> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Music music = new()
              {
                  Name = request.Model.Name,
                  ImageUrl = request.Model.ImageUrl,
                  IsUsable = request.Model.IsUsable,
                  Lyrics=request.Model.Lyrics
              };

        music.AgeRate = await _ageRateRepositoryAsync.GetAsync(x => x.Id == request.Model.AgeRateId);

        foreach (var moodId in request.Model.MoodIds)
        {
            Mood existMood = await _moodRepositoryAsync.GetAsync(x => x.Id == moodId);

            if (existMood != null)
            {
                music.Moods.Add(existMood);
            }
        }

        foreach (var categoryId in request.Model.CategoryIds)
        {
            Category existCategory = await _categoryRepositoryAsync.GetAsync(x => x.Id == categoryId);

            if (existCategory != null)
            {
                music.Categories.Add(existCategory);
            }
       }

       await _musicRepositoryAsync.CreateAsync(music);
       await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();

       return Response<CreatedMusicResponse>.Success(music.Adapt<CreatedMusicResponse>(), 201);
    }
}
```

[image: Request Model]

EF Core 7, many-to-many relationship

````
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Music> Musics { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AgeRate> AgeRates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Mood> Moods { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Music>().Navigation(m => m.Moods).AutoInclude();
        builder.Entity<Music>().Navigation(c => c.Categories).AutoInclude();
        builder.Entity<Music>().Navigation(c => c.AgeRate).AutoInclude();
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}```
````

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Could you share the definition of your table cause it is obvious a unique constraint defined in the table is violated(very likely the **agerate table**). Since you don’t check existing agerateid in your  code, it could be the cause.

Comment: @Ronaldoz This error is present in all relevant tables. The main problem here is that it tries to create "agerate" data as if it were new data. This AgeRate allready exist. Just I want relationship with my new music record.

Comment: You have existing records in mood/category/agerate tables, and want to insert new records into music table with the ids within the records above. It will be great if you can share the table creation statement of relative tables so that we can avoid exceptions.

Comment: I used code first and share my dbcontext up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved :

```
   public async Task<T> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        return await _dbSet.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(filter);
    }
```

I removed AsNoTracking() and working now.

Answer (score 0):

The many-to-many relationship can be explained simply this way according to document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#examples

> My sample is simplified

```
public class Music
{
    …
    public int MusicID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mood> Moods { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AgeRate> AgeRates { get; set; }
}
```

> Autoinclude in not necessary in DbContext

When need to create relationship with existing entities, use Add

```
public async Task<Music> ManyToMany()
{
    …
    //get the mood
    ICollection<Mood> moods = new List<Mood> {
    _context.Mood.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MoodID == request.Model.AgeRateId) };
    
    _context.Music.Add(new Music { Name = "MusicMoodName1", Url = "MusicMoodUrl1", Moods = moods });

    //same as category/agerate
    …
    _context.SaveChanges();
    …
}
```

Relationship Table is automatically created and when executed, it is successfully inserted.

[image]

Music table

[image]

MoodMusic table

[image]